# How to add pagination in ASP.NET Core MVC, on dynamically created table within AJAX call

Tags: c#, ajax, pagination, asp.net-core-mvc

Cshtml:

```
<!--Grid view details-->
<div class="divGrid" id="divGridSales" style="display:none;">
    <div class="table-responsive" id="ItemTableDiv" style="float: none;">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table tblView" id="tblViewPartDetails">
                <thead id="itemTblHeaderColumns">
                </thead>
                <tbody id="ItemConfigGrid">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On dropdown change event I am creating table dynamically as follows,

```
$("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
    $("#divGridSales").css({ display: "none" });

    var id = {};
    id.pLobID = $('#ddlLOB').val();
    id.pCountryID = $('#ddlCountry').val();

    if (id.pCountryID > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../Controller/Method",
            data: id,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    debugger;
                    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                        var tableHeader = $('#itemTblHeaderColumns')
                        $("#itemTblHeaderColumns tr").remove();
                        var trHeader = $('<tr /> ').appendTo(tableHeader);
                        /////This is used to bind columns
                        trHeader.append('<th class="trheaderTable" style="width: 12%;"> Part Number </th>');//PartNumber
                        trHeader.append('<th class="trheaderTable" style="width: 5%;"> Action </th>');//Action
                        ///This is used to bind rows
                        var tbody = $('#ItemConfigGrid');
                        $("#ItemConfigGrid tr").remove();
                        for (var iRow = 0; iRow < data.length; iRow++) {
                            var tr = $('<tr /> ').appendTo(tbody);
                            tr.append('<td>' + data[iRow].partNumber + '</td>');
                            tr.append('<td><a href="#" id="hlinkView" class="ti-eye" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onclick="getPartDetailsByPartNumber(' + data[iRow].partNumber + ')"></a></td>');
                        }
                        $('#tblViewPartDetails').DataTable();
                        $("#divGridSales").css({ display: "block" });
                   }
                    else {
                        alert('Something went to wrong!');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here on table `tblViewPartDetails` I have to add pagination

**Note**: I have tried the DataTable plugin, first time it shows data as required. But the next time, when dropdown changes, that time all data displays (pagination does not work).

Comment: I'm not seeing any problem with your code, can you explain more about the problem or issue that you are facing? I also didn't see any request parameters related to pagination, how are you deciding the current page num on the server-side?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty  I need to add pagination for this dynamically added HTML table, I have tried for DataTable plugin but that didn't work as mentioned in Note.

Comment: I understood that you want to implement the pagination. The code you have now will work as expected, but the only thing is how are you handling the number of records that you need to send from the server. Ex: First Load, Current Page is 1, then load the first 1 records, Second Page, Current Page is 2, then you need to skip the first 10 records and get the last 10 records. You can do this same for the DataTable as well, just clear the DataTable using `$('#myTable').dataTable().clear();`

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty thanks for reply, but my actual requirement is I have to add pagination to whole data at client side & it will display on Dropdown's change event. with DataTable first time it is working fine as required, but when I change Drop down that time it displays all data with pagination but with previous record count also search text box is not clearing. when we search new text that time it works as required. Can we add web grid like functionality in ASP Dot Net Core.

Comment: Can you please post the implementation that you tried for DataTable?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty just edited above code to show how I have used DataTable plugin

Comment: Did you try this $('#tblViewPartDetails').DataTable( {
    paging: true
} );

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty I have tried as you suggested, but getting alert as following

"DataTables warning: table id=tblViewPartDetails - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3"

after clicking ok, it is displaying whole data again with count of previous data

Comment: Please suggest any other solution apart from DataTable plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class Country
{
    public int pCountryID { get; set; }
    public int pLobID { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<select id="ddlCountry">
    <option value="0">Select a Value</option>
    <option value="1">Shanghai</option>
    <option value="2">Nanjing</option>
    <option value="3">Wuhan</option>
</select>
<div class="divGrid" id="divGridSales" style="display:none;">
    <div class="table-responsive" id="ItemTableDiv" style="float: none;">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table tblView" id="tblViewPartDetails">
                <thead>
                   
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
            $("#divGridSales").css({ display: "none" });
            var id = {};
            id.pLobID = $('#ddlLOB').val();
            id.pCountryID = $('#ddlCountry').val();
            var columns = [];
            if (id.pCountryID > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Home/Test",
                    data: id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        columnNames = Object.keys(data[0]);
                        console.log(columnNames);
                        for (var i in columnNames) {
                            columns.push({
                                data: columnNames[i],
                                title: columnNames[i]
                            });
                        }
                        $("#divGridSales").css({ display: "block" });
                        $('#tblViewPartDetails').DataTable({
                            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                            "serverSide": false, // for process server side
                            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
                            "bDestroy": true,   //for reinitialize the datatable
                            "data": data,
                            "columns": columns
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    List<Country> countries = new List<Country>()
    {
        new Country (){pLobID=1,pCountryID=1},
        //more hard coded data...      
        new Country (){pLobID=313,pCountryID=3},       
    };       
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult Test(Country model) 
    {
        var data = countries.Where(a => a.pCountryID == model.pCountryID)
                            .ToList();
        return Json(data);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

**UPDATE:**

You need add a new item in `columns` to put the button in this column. Then remember to add this button by using `columnDefs` method in Datatable:

```
<script>
    $("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
        $("#divGridSales").css({ display: "none" });
        var id = {};
        id.pLobID = $('#ddlLOB').val();
        id.pCountryID = $('#ddlCountry').val();
        var columns = [];
        if (id.pCountryID > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/Test",
                data: id,
                success: function (data) {
                    columnNames = Object.keys(data[0]);
                    console.log(columnNames);
                    for (var i in columnNames) {
                        columns.push({
                            data: columnNames[i],
                            title: columnNames[i]
                        });
                    }
                    //add this...
                    columns.push({
                        data: "Operation",
                        title: "Operation"
                    })
                    $("#divGridSales").css({ display: "block" });
                    $('#tblViewPartDetails').DataTable({
                        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                        "serverSide": false, // for process server side
                        "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                        "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
                        "bDestroy": true,   //for reinitialize the datatable
                        "data": data,
                        "columns": columns,
                        "columnDefs": [
                            {
                                // The `data` parameter refers to the data for the cell.
                                // The `rows`argument is an object representing all the data for the current row.
                                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                    return "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-delete' onclick='Delete(" + row.pLobID + ")'>Delete</button>||<button class='btn btn-danger btn-delete' onclick='Edit(" + row.pLobID + ")'>Edit</button>";
                                },
                                "targets": -1  // -1 is the last column, 0 the first, 1 the second, etc.
                            }
                        ]
                        
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    function Delete(data) {
        alert(data);
    };
    function Edit(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
</script>
```

If you want to make column hidden, you could add the following code to `columnDefs`:

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        // The `data` parameter refers to the data for the cell.
        // The `rows`argument is an object representing all the data for the current row.
        "render": function (data, type, row) {
            return "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-delete' onclick='Delete(" + row.pLobID + ")'>Delete</button>||<button class='btn btn-danger btn-delete' onclick='Edit(" + row.pLobID + ")'>Edit</button>";
        },
        "targets": -1  // -1 is the last column, 0 the first, 1 the second, etc.
    },

      //add here.....
    {
        "targets": [0],//0 the first, 1 the second, etc.
        "visible": false
    }
]
```

Comment: tried as you suggested, but getting error as follows, while "columns.push({"

Error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: columns is not defined"

Comment: Hi @MTaj, it seems you do not define columns, please check my code more carefully. You may miss `var columns = [];`.

Comment: Thanks lot for your precious help, now working fine.
Just one more help how do we add Action column as in above code or how do we display/hide Columns.
as of now all columns are displaying as it is coming to us from DB.
as per my requirement I am creating Dynamically HTML (shown in above code) table with one action column having hyper link for displaying details in popup.
Can we achieve this by Datatable plugin.

Comment: still main issue not resolved @Rena, as I am creating dynamic table for that how to achieve, I am not getting.

Comment: Hi @MTaj, what's the error message? What is your code now? Please update. Actually I could create dynamic table and you could see it in the shared gif.

Comment: yes you are right that you have created table dynamically. but I have to perform CRUD operations on data means eg. I have to add columns having edit/update like hyperlinks on it.

Comment: OK. I know your requirement now. So you need to add CRUD operation by button. Let me check.

Comment: also can I hide columns as I need to bring data only but don't want show on grid

Comment: Thanks lot @Rena for your support n showing interest in my issue, I have accepted your answer now I will check second one which you have updated. Sorry for late reply as I was busy with my laptop issue.

Comment: Last but least help @rena, Please tell me how do I find out all useful **_methods_** of **Datatable Plugin**.

Comment: Hi @rena all things as you told working fine except following hyperlink

`return "<a href='#' id='hlinkView' class='ti-eye' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal' onclick='getPartDetailsByPartNumber(" + row.partNumber + ")'></a>";`
here on click of hyperlink only popup displaying but onclick function not get called.
please suggest me what am I missing here.

also can we add CSS or style to columns.

Comment: Hi @MTaj, I have tested in my project. It will firstly calls the onclick function then the modal popup. Not sure what did you do. I think you could post a new thread and share detailed code.

Comment: Hi @Rena. I sorted out issue, issue with parameter row.partNumber which I am passing to function. If I pass number it works fine, issue with string parameter. here I am not getting what am I missing.

Comment: I got solution for above issue as below,

changed return call as,
```return "<a href='#' id='hlinkView' class='ti-eye' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal'></a>";```

& method created as below,
```
    $('#tblViewPartDetails tbody').on('click', '.ti-eye', function () {
        //debugger;
        var table = $('#tblViewPartDetails').DataTable();
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = table.row(tr).data();
        //console.log(data.partNumber);
        getPartDetailsByPartNumber(data.partNumber, data.lobid, data.countryCode);
    });
```